# Process for a DSP to connect to FBX

Tags: facebook, ads

I am working in the direction of being Demand Side Platform for Real time bidding. I wanted to know the process for a DSP in order to connect with Facebook AdExchange some of the questions being:
1. What is Facebook's minimum criteria for letting me integrate with its AdExchange
2. What will be the process like i.e how to connect with a FB representative, how long will it take for this process
3. How does the cookie synching work with FBX

It would be very help if someone could provide me details regarding the above.

Thanking all in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is one of the three giants (the other two being [Google](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/) and [AppNexus](http://www.appnexus.com/)) that play outside of [OpenRTB](http://openrtb.github.io/OpenRTB/) mainstream. All those have custom integration protocols and complicated legal onboarding procedures. Specifics of the FBX is that you have to implement connection within a certain timeline. Once you failed there will be no other chance to integrate with Facebook. Also there are certain commitments on minimum traffic volumes you will buy and there is a lot of work on the legal side of it. Again, if anything is not in place by the end of integration period the window of opportunity will close forever. In short Facebook is for big players, not for start-ups, and even large companies sometimes line up to integrate with FBX.

1. If $100k in monthly media spend scares you off, FBX may be not the best choice. (Please treat it as a rough guess, I don't really know).
2. Details of FBX integration process are confidential, it is very unlikely someone will tell you before you contact FB representative.
3. You will find the details in the documentation which will be provided by Facebook representative.

As an aside note, there are lots of other exchanges you may want to connect to with less strict legal/technical requirements and with relatively good traffic quality. In display those could be [Pubmatic](http://www.pubmatic.com/index-eng.php), [Rubicon](http://www.rubiconproject.com/), [OpenX](http://openx.com/), [FMX](http://www.federatedmedia.net/), etc. In mobile there are [MoPub](http://www.mopub.com/), [Smaato](http://www.smaato.com/), [InMobi](http://inmobi.com/), [MobClix](http://www.mobclix.com/) etc. There are many many others. There is also a huge project by one of RTB technology leaders [IPONWEB](http://www.iponweb.com/), which is called [BidSwitch](http://www.iponweb.com/bidswitch/what-is-it/) - it offers access to a whole lot of supply sources via single integration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you..this really helped me. Do you know in general what is the procedure so as to connect with any of the ad exchange and start bidding? How long does it take in terms of time and efforts?

Comment: @user3545015 Generally you need to sort out legal part of it and implement SSP protocol for bidding. Technically it takes about a month sometimes even more for a typical DSP to integrate. Best companies can connect within two weeks including testing.

Comment: @nab whom to talk to start integration with those exchanges? 'contact us' forms does not get answered. thanks for the good information.